# Cannot print to Canon MX430: Printer appears as offline when it isn't

Tags: windows-8, drivers, printing, network-printer, canon-pixma

I have Windows 8 installed on my 2015 HP ENVY 750 Desktop PC since last year, but my Canon MX430 series Printer has not been printing. I am getting the following warning stating that the printer is offline:

[image: Canon MX430 series Printer warning message]

- All the cables are plugged in and the printer is on. In fact I was using our Mac Mini to print wireless.
- My desktop is on the same network as the network printer.
- The last time I had a similar problem my brother had me update the computer software and install some drivers but I'm not sure if it was offline or not recognized last time.

How can I trobuleshoot this issue? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found here [My MX430 keeps going offline and won't print](http://community.usa.canon.com/t5/Printer-Multifunction-Support/My-MX430-keeps-going-offline-and-won-t-print/td-p/33417/):

**Try this** 
Printer offline may indicate that the printer driver is not configured properly.  Please try the following to resolve the issue:

1. Click Start.
2. Click Control Panel.
3. Click Hardware and Sound.
4. Click Devices and Printers.
5. Right click the MX430 Printer and click Printer Properties.
6. Click the Ports tab.
7. Make sure that the checkmark is on the port that starts with CNBJNP, then click OK and try to print.
   If the CNBJNP port was already selected please try right clicking the MX430 printer and click See Whats Printing.  When the print queue opens, click Printer and remove the checkmark on Use Printer Offline by clicking on it, then try printing again.
   Did this answer your question? Please click the Accept as Solution button so that others may find the answer as well.